# At what point can a final variable in Java no longer be modified?

Tags: java, initialization, variable-assignment, final

Take this block of code for example:

```
private final House house;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    house = new House("Robinsons");
    house.setColor("Red");
}
```

Would this be a valid use of a final variable? Is it legal to modify it once it has technically been initialized but is being modified while still in the constructor?

Comment: Please put that code into an IDE or `.java` file and try to compile it...

Comment: `non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context`

Answer (score 2):

`final` on a variable means the variable cannot be re-assigned after it's been assigned the first time.

Assuming your code compiled, this

```
house = new House("Robinsons");
```

is an assignment, so `house` would be assigned for the first time.

This

```
house.setColor("Red");
```

is a method invocation that does not affect the variable `house`. It affects the object referenced by the variable `house`.

Comment: So at any point in the code, that kind of operation on a final variable would be valid?

Comment: @SaxSalute If by _kind of operation_ you mean method invocation or field access, then yes, as long as the variable has been definitely initialized at that point in the code.

Comment: @SaxSalute final means that you cannot reasign the variable again to a new object, but you can invoke methods or field access if they are visible in your context

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you left some out, is this the complete code?

```
public class House {
    private final House house;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        house = new House("Robinsons");
        house.setColor("Red");
    }

    public House(String houseName) {
        // do something
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        // do something 
    }
}
```

If so, there are a number of problems with this.

1. a final variable needs to be given a value right on declaration. And to answer your question, <strike>once a final variable is given a value (when declaring it), that will be the last time you can modify it.</strike> (refer to comments below, thanks exception1!).
2. House is not a static variable, so it cannot be accessed from inside the `main` method, either make `house` a static variable, which I wouldn't recommend. Or declare an instance inside the `main` method before using it.

Comment: *a final variable needs to be given a value right on declaration.* Well, technically, this is true for Java 1.0. Since Java 1.1 you can use **blank final** variables, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_%28Java%29#Blank_final

Answer (score 0):

From the [JLS §8.1.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3):

> **A blank final instance variable must be definitely assigned (§16.9) at the end of every constructor (§8.8) of the class in which it is declared; otherwise a compile-time error occurs.**

In effect, this means that, after your object is constructed, either with your own custom constructor, or the default no-arg constructor, your `final` variable ***must*** be assigned a value.

As it stands, that isn't a valid use of `final`; the default no-arg constructor isn't capable of assigning it a value during its construction.

A slightly more appropriate usage would be this:

```
public class PersonsHome {
    private final House house;

    public PersonsHome(String houseName) {
        house = new House(housename);
    }
}
```

`house` is definitely assigned at the end of construction<sup>1</sup>, so the contract for `final` is satisfied.

<sup>1:  I did mention the default no-arg constructor; that's only created [if there's no other constructor around.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9)</sup>